# How to include hypens and apostrophes for a PHP Regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a password regex in PHP that should return false for any string that has at least **one** character that is not:

- a lowercase letter **a-z**
- an uppercase letter **A-Z**
- a number **0-9**
- a whitespace **" *"**
- a punctuation symbol **:,.!().?";**

So far I have this:

```
    <?php

    $password = 'azAZ0  giggles   9*":,.!()    .?";';
    $regex1 = '#^[a-zA-Z0-9" *":,.!().?";\']+$#i';

    if (preg_match($regex1, $password)) {
        echo "A match was found.";
    } else {
        echo "A match was not found.";
    }
    ?>
```

Does this seem to be working as I intend it to, or do you see any glaring errors?

And what should I add to the regex so that it should return false for any string that has at least **one** character that is not:

- a hyphen **-**

Comment: Your code should give you an error/warning. Please enable error reporting and add the error message you get. Add `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the beginning of your script for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is pretty close to the target, but not totally correct.

I would use this one:

```
$regex1 = '/^[a-z0-9 :,.!().?";\'-]+$/i';
```

Points of interest:

- Moved the hyphen to the end of the list, so that it won't be mistaken for a character range delimiter
- Included an apostrophe by escaping it with a backslash, as per PHP's string escaping rules
- Removed the `A-Z` part since the regex includes the case-insensitive modifier
- Replaced `*` (which in this context means "a space or an asterisk") with just a space -- if you want to also allow tabs and newlines as part of the password (unlikely), replace it with `\s`

Comment: Space and tab for passwords is not unlikely.

Comment: @hakre: *Tabs* and *newlines* are quite hard to enter if you 're filling in a HTML form. Spaces can be common, agree on that.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to escape `'` using `\`. Try this

```
$regex1 = '#^[a-zA-Z0-9" *":,.!-().?";\']+$#i';
```

And you already seem to have `-` in the regex.

Comment: The dash must move to the end of the character class, or be escaped. Unless you mean `!` through `(`.

Comment: Next to that the double quote is in there three times. Just noting.

Answer (score 1):

Within a character class (denoted by square brackets in regex), a minus `-` is always introducing a range: `[A-Z]`.

You have `!-(`, which is no meaningful range and therefore does not do what you think. Solution:

- Move the `-` to the start or the end of the character class: `[-A-Z...]` / `[A-Z...-]`
- Escape the `-`: `[A-Z\-...]`

The other question you ask is *"How do I get a single quote into a PHP string?"* and really has nothing to do with regex. But "escape it" is the answer, of course.